# Remove sitecore/content from URLs

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there anyone here who has successfully removed sitecore/content from Sitecore's generated URLs.

I'm using Sitecore link manager to generate the URLs. I have a multi site setup and have enabled the Siteresolving option to true. However, it seems that there is no way to get this to work using the Link Manager.

GetFriendlyUrl methods seems to generate the URL without sitecore/content but unfortunately it's deprecated, so it's not an option here.

I've seen people suggesting overwriting the LinkProvider and write custom logic to remove sitecore/content from the URLs. This works but not a good solution really.

I would love to learn from other Sitecore experts here.

FYI: I'm using Sitecore 6.4.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you paste <sites> and <linkManager> from the sitecore config?

Comment: Could you paste how you use LinkProvider as well?

Comment: Read Mark's blog post.  You most likely have something set incorrectly in the <sites> section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution. My multi-site configuration was correct as per Mark's reference. What I did to fix the issue was to specify the site context to use when generating the links.

```
Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions URLOptions = new Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions();
URLOptions.Site = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite(Your_Site_Name);
return Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(ThisItem, URLOptions);
```

Answer (score 4):

Please ensure your sites are configured correctly from this blog post: [Have '/sitecore/content' in your URLs? Time to fix it.](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2012/02/have-sitecorecontent-in-your-link-time.html)

Comment: Though the information is more or less the same, I originally looked to this article for help: http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2011/05/01/sitecore-linkmanager-inside-out-muti-site-and-sub-site-setups/

It basically boils down to using targetHostName when hostName contains wildcards. TargetHostName is SC6 only afaik

Comment: Thanks Mark, that information lead me to the solution. My multi site configuration was correct. I just need to make sure to specify the proper context when generating the links. My answer below.

Answer (score 0):

fyi, I found it the following snippet useful for identifying the correct context site for my scenario where content for one site context was referenced from another site context.  I'm planning on updating the canonical link to notify google of the correct url.

```cs
public static Sitecore.Web.SiteInfo GetSite(this Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itemYouNeedToCheck)
{
return Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSiteInfoList()
    .OrderByDescending(x=> x.RootPath.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Database!="core" &&    itemYouNeedToCheck.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith(x.RootPath));
}
```